# How to Replace Hibernate with EclipseLink in WildFly.30.x

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, eclipselink

We have a java webapp running in Weblogic against an Oracle database. We are in the process to port it form WebLogic to Wildfly/JBoss. One issue we are encountering is we currently uses EclipseLink as the JPA provider and as we attempt to do a straight port to Wildfly with it's out of the box Hibernate JPA, we are running into issue after issue (persistance order, updates where we don't want, issues with existing database triggers, etc.)
So, instead of trying to fight with it, we are just thinking that we should be able to replace the Hibernate with EclipseLink as the JPA provider, but I am kind of stuck at where I can look for some documentation & more importantly of examples.
So want to see if any one have done this and any pointers, references, etc.

The webapp is being built with Maven and we are also switching from the 'javax.*' to 'jakarta.*' (not sure if that make any difference).

Thanks!

**Update:**
OK, so looks like according to the document reference, the module.xml definition seems to require the line:

```
<module name="java.rmi" export="true"/>
```

That removed the rmi exception, but generate a different trace:

```
13:52:11,611 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."settlement.war#reportingPersistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."settlement.war#reportingPersistenceUnit": jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 4.0.2.v202306161219): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [reportingPersistenceUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ClassConstants
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@31.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:187)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@31.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa@31.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:202)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1348)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```